# What can classes do that ids cannot do?

Tags: html, css

It looks like ids and classes are the exact same thing and have the same functionality, however ids are used just to show the coder/designer that they are only changing one item in those other similar items...  Is that true?

I watched this helpful video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZ4s1AvIDPM and that's the only difference I could tell.

Comment: You think we'll be able to explain it any better than the THOUSANDS of references on the web that talk about the similarities and differences?

Comment: I looked and couldn't find.

Comment: I thought that English words `identity` and `class` are quite simple to understand. Therefore `id` means unique identifier for the element of DOM while `class` designates a group of DOM elements which should share the same behaviour and/or look.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like ids and classes are the exact same thing and have the same functionality

Look again.

`id` specifically identifies an element.  Each element can have no more than one `id` and each `id` must be unique throughout the DOM.

`class` describes an element in a more generic way, associating it logically with other elements of the same `class`.  An element can have many classes, and the same class can be used many times throughout the DOM.

> ids are used just to show the coder/designer that they are only changing one item in those other similar items... Is that true?

No, that's not true at all.  `id`s uniquely identify (hence "id") elements.  They can be used by a developer or a designer to target a specific element for some purpose (altering it, styling it, observing it, and so on).

The fact that the person is selecting an `id` does guarantee that they are targeting only one element (assuming that element exists, otherwise zero elements) as long as the document is well-formed (doesn't break the rule of not re-using `id` values, in which case the code is incorrect and behavior is undefined).

Conversely, when selecting based on a `class` value, any number of elements may be selected.  So any developer and/or designer (or any other role) would bear that in mind and not assume that there's only one element.

Comment: What is a DOM please...?

Comment: @user2252443: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM  Essentially it's the HTML document made up of all of the elements therein.

Comment: Thanks David.  You rock man.

Comment: DOM stands for `Document Object Model` which is a tree representation of HTML/XML document. Every element in the document is a node in DOM tree. Every element except for `document root` has a parent node and elements can have children. There are two types of nodes: tag nodes and text nodes. Text nodes can't have children.